# finding a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Consider any two pairs of three distinct points $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $(y_1, y_2, y_3) $ in $ℝ^2$

I have to prove that there is a homeomorphism of $ ℝ^2 $ with its standard topology to itself mapping $x_{i}$ to $y_{i}$ for each $i = 1, 2, 3 $
is there a possibility to find the expression of this homeomorphism by reasoning geometrically?
Hints are welcome .

Comment: Just translation by the vector $(y_1 -x_1 ,y_2-x_2 ,y_3 -x_3)$.

Comment: @TheWildCat $x_1$ is itself a vector, I think.

Comment: @TheWildCat i dont think  it just a translation , the vector of translation you proposed is in R^3

Comment: My idea is the following: Take open neighborhoods $U_i$ of $x_i$ and $V_i$ of $y_i$ such that $U_i \cap U_j = \phi$ and $V_i \cap V_j = \phi$ if $i \neq j$, and homeomorphisms $f_i:U_i \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} V_i$ such that $f_i (x_i) = y_i$. Now, we just need to show that the $f_i$'s can be extended to a homeo on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  In case I can't prove the last part, maybe you can.
Also, for potences, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$, please use ^ followed by the number. Use ^{} if it's more than one character.

Comment: The existence of such homeomorphisms $f_i$ can be seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462768/for-any-x-y-in-the-interior-of-the-unit-ball-dn-there-is-a-homeomorphism?rq=1

Comment: I am not sure what your background is, but using a bit of fundamental groups or algebraic topology, you can prove that these maps can be extended using something similar to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029171/show-that-if-h-is-extendable-to-a-continuous-map-of-bbb-rn-into-y-then
Alternatively, just use a bump function, which is not only continuous, but in fact smooth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb{R^3}$ ?

Comment: @Bliipbluup I don't understand the point to mention bump functions.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ are in general position (non aligned).

A) Here is a geometrical reasoning.

1. Bring the triangles to a common origin by respective translations $T_{-x_3}$ and $T_{-y_3}$, then
2. Apply the (unique) linear transformation $L$ mapping the ordered pair $(x_1-x_3,x_2-x_3)$ onto the ordered pair $(y_1-y_3,y_2-y_3)$, which is given by matrix:

$$L=[y_1-y_3,y_2-y_3][x_1-x_3,x_2-x_3]^{-1}$$

(with slight abuses of notation, in particular taking vectors instead of their coordinates in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$).

Therefore a solution is provided by composition:

$$T_{y_3} \circ L \circ  T_{-x_3}\tag{1}$$

which, using homogeneous coordinates, can be written

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&y_{31}\\0&1&y_{32}\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p&q&0\\r&s&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-x_{31}\\0&1&-x_{32}\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

"cousin" of the following explicit projective transform:

$$\begin{cases}x'=\dfrac{ax+by+c}{gx+hy+i}\\y'=\dfrac{dx+ey+f}{gx+hy+i}\end{cases}$$

What we have obtained is a homeomorphism because all the involved operations in (1) are bijective (invertible) and continuous.

B) **Edit**: a different way to obtain this homeomorphism still in a geometric way is to consider the following transformation:

$$M \in \mathbb{R^2} \ \mapsto \ M' \in \mathbb{R^2} $$

by computing the barycentrical coordinates $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ of $M$ with respect to triangle $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and then defining $M'$ plainly by taking the point with the same barycentrical coordinates with respect to triangle $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$.

Comment: See my Edit, providing a second solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a supplement to Jean Marie's answer which covers the case that both triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ are in general position.

If we have a tripel $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ of distinct points which are not in general position, we shall show how to find a homeomorphism $h$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $(h(z_1),h(z_2),h(z_3))$ are in general position. This will cover the general case.

The points $z_i$ lie on a line $L$ in $\mathbb R^2$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $L$ is the $x$-axis (if this is not the case, use an affine transformation $g$ such that $g(L)$ is the $x$-axis). Write $z_i = (a_i,0)$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that $a_1 < a_2 < a_3$. Now define
$$h(a,b) = \begin{cases} (a,b) & a \le a_2 \\ (a,b + a - a_2) & a \ge a_2 \end{cases}$$
This is a homeomorphism such that $h(z_1) = z_1, h(z_2) = z_2$ and $h(z_3) = (a_3, a_3-a_2)$. These three points are in general position.